# Direct limit of the sequence $E_{0} \hookrightarrow E_{1} \hookrightarrow \cdots$ in the category of Banach spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, category-theory, banach-spaces, homological-algebra

Recently I have been reading the paper *The categorical origins of Lebesgue integration* by Tom Leinster (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.00412.pdf). In this paper, he said that：

> For $n \geq 0$, let $E_{n}$ be the subspace of $L^{p}[0,1], (1\leq p<\infty)$ consisting of the equivalence classes of step functions constant on each of the (open) intervals $\left(\frac{i-1}{2^{n}}, \frac{i}{2^{n}}\right)$, $\left(1 \leq i \leq 2^{n}\right)$. Write $E=\bigcup_{n \geq 0} E_{n}$, which is the space of step functions whose points of discontinuity are dyadic rationals. Then $E$ is dense in the set of all step functions on $[0,1]$, which in turn is dense in $L^{p}[0,1]$; so $E$ is dense in $L^{p}[0,1]$. It follows that $L^{p}[0,1]$ is the colimit (direct limit) of the diagram $E_{0} \hookrightarrow E_{1} \hookrightarrow \cdots$ in the category $\mathbf{\text{Ban}}$ of Banach spaces with linear contractions as morphisms.

I know that the category $\mathbf{\text{Ban}}$ is cocomplete, i.e., the colimit of any diagram exists (because it has coproducts and coequalizers). However, I just have no idea **why the density of $E$ in $L^p[0,1]$ implies just that $L^p[0,1]$ is the colimit of the increasing sequence $E_{0} \hookrightarrow E_{1} \hookrightarrow \cdots$ in the category $\mathbf{\text{Ban}}$ of Banach spaces with linear contractions**? I thought about this for two days but didn't figure out anything. Can anyone give a convincing or inspiring explanation?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't give a rigorous proof but I can convince you by the following: Firstly, a direct limit for the set category is just the union (to check, use the universality). Secondly, in a category where topology matters, an epi is a mapping whose image is DENSE, not necessarily the whole space.

Comment: @RichardChen Thank you for your comment. However, the direct limit of this sequence in the category of Banach space here is unfortunately not this union (I have checked that before). It is not that obvious as the category of sets. Also, the union is not a Banach space. We cannot talk about direct limits in different categories.

Comment: You must take the completion (alternatively the closure in an ambient Banach space). Whats the purpose of the proof? To show that $L^p$ is Banach? Then you are going in circles, since the conlculsion $\lim E_n = L^p$ requires $L^p$ to be Banach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The density of $E$ in $L^p[0,1]$ means that $L^p[0,1]$ is the completion of $E$ as a (pseudo-)normed vector space. The relation with colimits has to do with how these completions function.

Banach spaces are a reflective subcategory of the category of (pseudo-)normed spaces: if $V$ is a (pseudo-)normed vector space, then it is equipped with a completion map $V\to\hat V$ for $\hat V$ a Banach space, such that any other map $V\to B$ with $B$ a Banach space factors uniquely as $V\to\hat V\to B$.

Consequently, any cocone $V_i\to B$ factors uniquely as $V_i\to(\mathrm{colim}_i V_i)\to B$ and then as $V_i\to\hat{\mathrm{colim}_i V_i}\to B$. Thus the completion of a colimit of Banach spaces considered as pseudo-normed vector spaces is the colimit of them considered as Banach spaces.

Now the union $E$ of $E_0\hookrightarrow E_1\hookrightarrow\cdots$ is the direct limit in the category of (pseudo-)normed spaces, so it being dense in $L^p[0,1]$ means $L^p[0,1]$ is the direct limit of $E_0\hookrightarrow E_1\hookrightarrow\cdots$ in the category of Banach spaces.